# Should I only use myisam or also innodb for my mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, myisam

I am not sure if I should use myisam or innodb for my mysql DB.

My needs:

**I will use full-text search. Both myisam and innodb support this since mysql 5.6**

**I will only do inner-joins between different tables**

**About 75% of all queries will be SELECT, that has inner-joins**

Will myisam be best for me consider the stuff above?

**Also, can I do inner-joins between one table that runs myisam to a table that runs innodb?**

Eg my users table is innoDB, I do a inner-join from that table to the product table that runs on myisam. In order to get all products for a user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb?rq=1

Comment: I usually default to InnoDB due to transaction support. I don't think there are any restrictions on doing joins between tables with different DB engines, but as I recall MyISAM doesn't support FK constraints.

Comment: MyISAM seems best for frequent select queries. But if I am inner-joining to a innoDB when doing a select query, would that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you have written here, what you are looking for, does not state which one of the engines would fit you better. Both meets your requirements.

A very simplified way to determine what engine suites you better is if you are looking for speed or consistency, eg: `myisam` for speed and `innodb` for consistency, but you will then need to work with FK constraints. The comment of Hanky that linked to [MyISAM versus InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb?rq=1) tells you more about the differences.

---

If you are looking to do a full-text index, you could also have a look at [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)